# Rails execute script as background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, delay

I've a ruby script that has been implemented as an independent functionality.
Now I would like to execute this script in my rails environament, with the added difficulty of executing it as a background job, because it needs a great amount of time processing.

After adding the delayed_job gem, I've tryied calling the following sentence:

```
delay.system("ruby my_script.rb")
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms
TypeError (can't dump anonymous module: #<Module:0x007f8a9ce14dc0>):
   app/controllers/components_controller.rb:49:in `create'
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling the `self.delay` method from your controller [won't work](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/371), because DJ will try to serialize your controller into the Job. You'd better create a class to handle your task then flag its method as asynchronous :

```
class AsyncTask
  def run
    system('ruby my_script.rb')
  end
  handle_asynchronously :run
end
```

In your controller :

```
def create
    ...
    AsyncTask.new.run
    ...
end
```

See the second example in the "Queing Jobs" section of the [readme](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

Comment: Ok, and how can I debug it? Puts or logger are not being effective inside the run method.

Comment: Did you try with `Delayed::Worker.logger` ?

Comment: `Delayed::Worker.logger "test log"` should write the string in the console, isn't it?
It's not working. By the way, I've implemented the async task as Erez post, the method is the same?

Comment: Did you check the log/test.log file ?

Comment: There isn't the file.
Should I write `Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger` or using it as logger directly?

Comment: DelayedJob uses the Rails logger by default (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/worker.rb). Did you have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507765/delayed-job-not-logging ?

Comment: Rails log files can be found in the log directory, each one corresponding to an environment : test.log, development.log and so on.

Comment: Fixed. I'm really sorry, I didn't realised that to make delayed_job run, `rake jobs:work` was needed. Thanks, Jef.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jef stated the best solution is to create a custom job.
The problem with Jef's answer is that its syntax (as far as I know) is not correct and that's his job handles a single system command while the following will allow you more customization:

```
# lib/system_command_job.rb
class SystemCommandJob < Struct.new(:cmd)
  def perform
    system(cmd)
  end
end
```

Note the cmd argument for the Struct initializer. It allows you to pass arguments to your job so the code would look like:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(SystemCommandJob.new("ruby my_script.rb"))
```

Comment: Erez, (as far as I can tell ;)) `handle_asynchronously` is correct use whenever "a method should always be run in the background" (quoted from DJ README) I tried to answer with concise code and close to the examples provided by the documentation

Comment: Erez, to debug Delayed::Worker.logger is not working, any ideas?