# Delayed_job is no longer logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, delayed-job

For some reason, my Rails app is no longer logging my DelayedJob gem's activity, either to a separate log (`delayed_job.log`) or to the main Rails development log. I am also using the Workless gem, should this be relevant.

It used to say things like this:

```
2013-06-07T19:16:25-0400: [Worker(delayed_job.workless host:MyNames-MacBook-Pro.local       pid:28504)] Starting job worker
2013-06-07T19:16:38-0400: [Worker(delayed_job.workless host:MyNames-MacBook-Pro.local pid:28504)] MyApp#scrape completed after 13.0290
2013-06-07T19:16:38-0400: [Worker(delayed_job.workless host:MyNames-MacBook-Pro.local pid:28504)] 1 jobs processed at 0.0761 j/s, 0 failed ...
2013-06-07T19:16:43-0400: [Worker(delayed_job.workless host:MyNames-MacBook-Pro.local pid:28504)] Exiting...
```

But nothing is appearing anymore in any of the logs.

How can I make sure that DelayedJob activity logs to the main development log? I don't mind if it also logs to a separate log, but the important thing is that I see its activity in my Mac's console.

I have searched for answers to this issue online (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507765/delayed-job-not-logging) and nothing is working.

Here is my delayed_job_config.rb: (in config/initializers)

```
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 2
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 20.minutes
Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
Delayed::Worker.logger.auto_flushing = true
```

Please let me know if you'd like more code from my app - I'd be happy to provide it. Much thanks from a Rails newbie.

Comment: Remove the `Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger` and `Delayed::Worker.logger.auto_flushing` and see if it appears in delayed_job.log

Comment: I tried earlier, but it doesn't.

Comment: Is this production environment?

Comment: No, it is in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work. All thanks to Seamus Abshere's answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500200/getting-delayed-job-to-log). I put what he posted below in an initializer file. This got delayed_job to log to my development.rb file (huzzah!).

However, delayed_job still isn't logging into my console (for reasons I still don't understand). I solved that by opening a new console tab and entering `tail -f logs/development.log`.

Different from what Seamus wrote, though, `auto-flushing=true` is deprecated in Rails 4 and my Heroku app crashed. I resolved this by removing it from my initializer file and placing it in my `environments/development.rb` file as `config.autoflush_log = true`. However, I found that neither of the two types of flushing were necessary to make this work.

Here is his code (without the auto-flushing):

```
file_handle = File.open("log/#{Rails.env}_delayed_jobs.log", (File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT))
# Be paranoid about syncing
file_handle.sync = true
# Hack the existing Rails.logger object to use our new file handle
Rails.logger.instance_variable_set :@log, file_handle
# Calls to Rails.logger go to the same object as Delayed::Worker.logger
Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
```

If the above code doesn't work, try replacing `Rails.logger` with `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER`.