# Have delayed_job log "puts", sql queries and jobs status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

Right now only the following are logged to `logs/delayed_job.log`:

```
2012-04-20T03:57:44+0000: Cacher completed after 5.3676
2012-04-20T03:57:44+0000: 1 jobs processed at 0.1744 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

What I'm trying to do is to have it also log all my `puts` as well as my SQL queries, like it does in development mode, except it still gets logged to `log/delayed_job.log`.

I tried to add the following to `initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` but no luck:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
Delayed::Worker.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

(all my `puts` get logged now, but no more job status logs and still no SQL queries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this link helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223681/445908

UPDATED:a bit more about puts. v.s logger:

I am not sure what your implementation of making "puts" result stored into log file. however I think it could be a much better choice to **ALWAYS** use "logger" instead of "puts". the reasons are:

1. in most of the cases, `puts` can slow down your performance(especially in production environment, in all of my past projects, `puts` is not allowed to appear in the source code) ( for java programmer, `System.out.println` is the same stuff)
2. always use `logger`, since it has 5 default levels: debug, info, warn, error, fatal, which could be control and beautifully formatted and filtered by tools such as `grep`.  e.g. can `puts` produce the log info below?

   ```
   07:27:48 INFO: in device_resource, options: queryem??ltres67@blur.com 
   07:27:48 INFO: cloudset: ??100
   ```

Comment: Have tried all 3 solutions and none of them works. In all cases `log/delayed_job.log` only gets the job status messages, and `development.log` gets the sql queries, but no where are my `puts` to be seen.

Comment: so how do you make your "puts" logged ? maybe you should let delayed_job know how that works.

Comment: so use something like `logger.info` instead?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying `puts` vs `logger`. Ended up using [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4648531/87158) to output my job status messages, SQL queries as well as my custom log messages to a dedicated delayed_job.log file.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails v3.2.13 you can do:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/delayed_job.log", Rails.logger.level)
Delayed::Worker.logger.auto_flushing = 1

#only reassign AR logger if we're in a delayed process(rake task or script/delayed_job)
if caller.last =~ /script\/delayed_job/ or (File.basename($0) == "rake" and ARGV[0] =~ /jobs\:work/)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Delayed::Worker.logger
end
```

But...ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger is being deprecated https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/buffered_logger.rb#L18

Plus, you probably want to rotate your logs right?  So this is better I think:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new("log/delayed_job.log", 5, 104857600)

if caller.last =~ /script\/delayed_job/ or (File.basename($0) == "rake" and ARGV[0] =~ /jobs\:work/)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Delayed::Worker.logger
end
```

The constructor says keep around 5 log files and rotate when the current log file hits 100Mb. See here for details: 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-c-new

Credit to: http://www.heedspin.com/2011/01/17/delayed-job-logging.html 
for the inspiration

Comment: where do you put this? in an initializer?

Comment: sure, or an environment file.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bit late for the OP, but here's a different approach: use a DelayedJob plugin to set the Rails (and ActiveRecord::Base) loggers from the one assigned to the Worker.

Two steps: in your Delayed Job initializer, do:

```
require 'delayed_job_log_setup'
Delayed::Worker.plugins << DelayedJobLogSetup
```

The plugin itself (which I obviously put in lib/delayed_job_log_setup.rb):

```
require 'delayed_job'

class DelayedJobLogSetup < Delayed::Plugin
  callbacks do |lifecycle|
    lifecycle.before(:execute) do |worker|
      Rails.logger = worker.logger
      ActiveRecord::Base.logger = worker.logger
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, my attempts to monkey-patch `Object#puts` to call the logger directly (inside the plugin) still doesn't do what the OP wanted.

Comment: Excellent answer. This works correctly for jobs that are classes as well as jobs using the simple .delay. syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to do the necessary log file configuration in the `script/delayed_job` file in your rails application. Mine now looks like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'

# This was added to make sure the DJ log has the same log level 
# as the rails app, and to ensure ActiveRecord uses the same log 
# when loaded inside a DJ worker process.
#
Delayed::Worker.logger ||= Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'), Rails.configuration.log_level)
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Delayed::Worker.logger

Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

Its pretty simple and clear what is going on with this approach.

And more importantly, there is no risk of messing up the AR logger for scenarios that don't involve a delayed worker process. This happened to us with a different approach similar to some of the other answers and caused numerous headaches and confusion.

Comment: For some reason, with Rails 3.2.16 under AWS Elastic Beanstalk on Passenger Standalone, this created a new, empty, numbered log file containing one SQL query every five seconds (each time the daemon runs). Looks like it went up to 100 files before stopping or maybe starting over. Also, it looks log_level cannot be set in the 'Logger.new` method.

Comment: @MarkBerry it sounds like you have some kind of log rotation component running outside of this code? I am unfamiliar with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so cannot really comment about what it might introduce.

Comment: I don't think this is related to log rotation, as rotated logs go into a subdirectory. It's like there was something causing it to create a new file (every five seconds) rather than overwriting an old one. I'm thinking it has to do with having this code in the script file rather than an initializer. Are you using this code in production? I've had better luck going back to setting the log in an initializer.