# Why would large job objects miss the queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid, delayed-job

In a rails project with `delayed_job`, and I am running into something strange.

I have an `article` Model, this model can be quite large, with many paragraphs of text in several fields.

If i do:

```
an_article.delay.do_something
```

the `Delayed::Job` that's created does not make it to the queue, it's never marked as failed or successful, and my logs don't acknowledge it's existance. However if i do

```
def self.proxy_method(article_id)
  an_article = Article.find(article_id)
  an_article.do_something
end

Article.proxy_method(an_article.id)
```

it works as intended.

Is there some unwritten rule about the size of job objects? Why would A not work, but B work?

One theory I have is that because I'm sort of close to my data cap for mongolab (430 / 496 mb) that the job never makes it to the db, but I have no log or error to really prove this.

---

NOTE: delayed_job using mongoid on heroku, rails 3.1

Comment: Starting point:  https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-Nothing_Happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have experienced, never push objects to the queue but rather use ids of objects. This is problematic and very hard to debug.

I have written a detailed post on this topic at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672001/226255

Comment: That is actually what I ended up doing, wish this was discussed in the docs... Thanks for reminding me about this question.

The root cause was that either the object was deleted before the job started, and in other cases the DB was up against the size cap.

Comment: Actually, the documentation pushes objects to the queue! This is what originally confused me. While this might work for some objects, some ActiveRecord objects were problematic and no logging was taking place.