# delayed job enqueues and dequeues job in database but does not execute code (locally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I use the following code to execute a method with delayed job:

```
class MyClass
   def send_a_text
      t = TwilioCommunicator.new
      t.send_sms("+15177416150","sent at #{Time.now}")
   end
   handle_asynchronously :send_a_text
end

t = MyClass.new
t.send_a_text
```

Without delayed job, this sends me a text message 100% of the time. With delayed job, I can see that this job is queued in the database and then dequeued but the code does not appear to run. I am testing locally and here is a snippet from my development.log:

```
AREL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("priority", "attempts", "handler", "last_error", "run_at", "locked_at", "failed_at", "locked_by", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (0, 0, '--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod 
object: !ruby/object:MyClass {}

method_name: :send_a_text_without_delay
args: []

', NULL, '2011-07-28 05:24:47.700969', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-07-28 05:24:47.701070', '2011-07-28 05:24:47.701070')
  AREL (2.9ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2011-07-28 05:24:51.191404', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:Stephen-B-Silverbergs-MacBook.local pid:3714' WHERE (id = 13 and (locked_at is null or locked_at < '2011-07-28 01:24:51.191404') and (run_at <= '2011-07-28 05:24:51.191404'))
  AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ("delayed_jobs"."id" = 13)
```

One thing I notice is the method_name is send_a_text_without_delay instead of send_a_text but this is the only strange thing I see. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the MyClass object in your Rails project?  If it is in not in `app/model`, then you need to reference the class in an initializer for Delayed_Job to work.  This issue fails silently in delayed_job.

See: [Rails Delayed Job & Library Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569396/rails-delayed-job-library-class)